# how do I call a apple script from shell script?

Tags: xcode, shell, applescript

how can I call apple script from shell script.

I have a shell script which I use in Run Script phase of my xcode project. Before this shell script is executed and I want to call another apple script?

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `osascript` utility.

Here's the intro to the utility, using `man osascript`:

```
OSASCRIPT(1)              BSD General Commands Manual             OSASCRIPT(1)

NAME
   osascript -- execute AppleScripts and other OSA language scripts

SYNOPSIS
   osascript [-l language] [-s flags] [-e statement | programfile] [argument ...]

DESCRIPTION
   osascript executes the given script.  It was designed for use with AppleScript,
   but will work with any Open Scripting Architecture (OSA) language. 
   ...
```

You may also be interested in the `osacompile` utility.